# EOSDigital.API.ExecutionException: SESSION_NOT_OPEN thrown randomly

Tags: c#, camera, edsdk, canon-sdk

We are using "Canon EOS Kiss X10" camera and code referred from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp).
Our application basically have 3 steps:

1. Open Session
2. Take Photo
3. Close Session

Application runs above steps loop, all of sudden we are getting error as below

> "Error in opening the camera session :
>   EOSDigital.API.ExecutionException: SESSION_NOT_OPEN --->
>   EOSDigital.API.SDKException: SESSION_NOT_OPEN" 
>   EOSDigital.API.ErrorHandler.CheckError(Object sender, ErrorCode
>   errorCode)  EOSDigital.API.Camera.b__73_0() 
>   EOSDigital.API.STAThread.ExecutionLoop()

As per SDK API documentation, this is kind of PTP error.
Checked few resources online found that firmware should be 1.0.2 [here](https://cweb.canon.jp/drv-upd/eosd/eoskissx10-firm.html) (Japanese)

But we have confirmed this behavior on 1.0.0 and it is working smoothly.
So is it due to some hardware connection issue e.g. USB port used to connect camera or cable had some issue or Microsoft PTP WIA minidriver etc. ?

Need to know, root cause for this, please provide us some light here.

Comment: it sounds like an issue with the USB cable and or port, have you tried it with a different one? and is there are reason you open and close the session in a loop? why not keep the session open?

Comment: Thank you very much for comments. Will try different port, regarding opening/closing session via loop, actually our application have lots of other process after closing session, so don't want to keep session alive till everything completed. By the way any way I can find out or prove cable/port has issue ?

Comment: if a new/different cable or port works, then you know the old cable/port had an issue, there's no simpler way to check than that.

Comment: @JohannesBildstein: It seems that error is due to AutoPower Off settings, when Camera is Idle for more than hour or so then after that (Only 1st time) when we try access Camera it gives error. Is there any way to get what is current AutoPower OFF settings from Camera ? CheckedCanonSDK.GetPropertyData method but seems some "MyMenuItems" inside "SDKStruct" has this. How to use this to get current AutoPowerOff settings ?

Comment: ah I didn't think of that but it's easy to fix. You can't set the AutoPower setting but you can handle  the `StateChanged` event: if `eventId` is `WillSoonShutDown` you can send the `ExtendShutDownTimer` command to the camera. This event will fire repeatedly.